# How to pop nested list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

`data['info']`

```
0     [(3.7.30.96, qqx, -7.654699802398682, ...
1     [(1.2.166.245, qwp, -10.170800209045...
2     [(3.7.124.119, qw8, -7.248400211334228...
3     [(3.7.34.129, qqt, -7.424499988555908,...
4     [(1.1.194.178, qqg, -6.1740999221801...
```

Here's what I need

```
      data_info1       data_info2        data_info3            data_info4
0     3.7.30.96             qqx          -7.654699802398682            ...
1     1.2.166.245,          qwp         -10.170800209045                 ...
2     3.7.124.119,          qw8          -7.248400211334228              ...
3     3.7.34.129,           qqt          -7.424499988555908              ...
4     1.1.194.178,          qqg          -6.1740999221801                ...
```

Here's what I try

```
data = data.join(pd.DataFrame(data.pop('info').values.tolist(), index=data.index))
```

Error Message

```
KeyError: 'info'
```

Comment: Seems like a fairly reasonable attempt. The error just says there's no column called `info` in the DataFrame. Also `3.7.30.96` is not valid in python unless that's a string. Can you provide a copyable DataFrame constructor which will build your DataFrame exactly as it appears for you?

Comment: Please add reproducible example (data).

Comment: You code works well with a sample data, e.g. `data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'info':[[1,2],[3,4]]})`. Since you already pop and reassign the data, make sure you don't accidentally run the code twice.